# SSLHandshakeException Unacceptable certificate because of device date time

Tags: android, sslhandshakeexception

When my app tried to connect internet I get following error message. The cause of this is the date time being incorrectly configured on the device.

Stack Trace :

```js
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Unacceptable certificate: CN = COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2, O = COMODO CA Limited, L = Salford, ST = Greater Manchester, C = GB
```

The following is the code that I use to connect. I want to connect internet without forcing user to change date time. Is it possible ? If possible , I will be gratefull if anyone helps me.

```js
URL url = new URL(link);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "");
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.connect();
InputStream is;
if (connection.getResponseCode() >= 400) {
  is = connection.getErrorStream();
} else {
  is = connection.getInputStream();
}
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append(reader.readLine()).append("\n");
String line = "0";
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  sb.append(line).append("\n");
}
is.close();
result = sb.toString();
```

Thanks alot.

Comment: This is a server side configuration. If the web server is under your control, you can change the default behaviour and force it to accept connections from out of sync devices. You should be able to do this on an HTTP, but not on HTTPS (Remember that this could create security problems and other bad things, avoid it at all costs)

Comment: Thank you very much, Seems like I will show a message to the user about date time issue on the device